To learn Schreier Sims Algorithm, need to learn O'Nan-Scott Theorem firstly or not necessary?
I am trying to learn the Schreier-Sims Algorithm, and some references also mention the O'Nan-Scott Theorem. Could you please advise if it is necessary to learn the O'Nan-Scott Theorem before studying the Schreier-Sims Algorithm? The O'Nan-Scott Theorem describes that the minimal normal subgroup is transitive and is a direct product of isomorphic simple groups. The Schreier-Sims Algorithm involves the concept of stabilizer chains. However, according to the order of topics in some references, the Schreier-Sims Algorithm is discussed before the O'Nan-Scott Theorem. Therefore, I am unsure if understanding the O'Nan-Scott Theorem is required for studying the Schreier-Sims Algorithm. Thank you very much.

No it is not necessary to learn the O'Nan-Scott Theorem in order to learn and understand the Schreier-Sims algorithm.
Apart from the very basic group theory, the only results required for the Schreier-Sims algorithm are the Orbit-Stabilizer theorem and Schreier's Theorem that describes generators of a subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ in terms of generators of $G$ and coset representatives of $H$ in $G$.

I'm really thankful for your incredibly clear and highly concise response.
